# Correct way to compute VGG features for Perceptual loss

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

While computing [VGG Perceptual loss](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.08155.pdf), although I have not seen, I feel it is alright to wrap the computation of VGG features for the GT image inside `torch.no_grad()`.

So basically I feel the following will be alright,

```
with torch.no_grad():
    gt_vgg_features = self.vgg_features(gt)

nw_op_vgg_features = self.vgg_features(nw_op)

# Now compute L1 loss
```

or one should use,

```
gt_vgg_features = self.vgg_features(gt)
nw_op_vgg_features = self.vgg_features(nw_op)
```

In both approaches `requires_grad` for VGG parameters is set `False` and VGG put in `eval()` mode.

The first approach will save a lot of GPU resources and feel should be numerically equal to the second one as no backpropagation is required through GT images. But in most implementations, I find the second approach used for computing VGG perceptual loss.

So which option we should go for implementing VGG perceptual loss in PyTorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    gt_vgg_features = self.vgg_features(gt)

nw_op_vgg_features = self.vgg_features(nw_op)
```

Although VGG is in `eval` mode and its parameters are kept fix, you still need to propagate gradients through it from the loss on the features to the output `nw_op`.
However, there's no reason to compute these gradients w.r.t `gt`.